# python image scrambeling porgram

Tags: python, image, image-processing, png, pixel

I'm writing an image scrambling and Unscrambling program. I'm transfering a custom seed to the random function in order scramble the image pixels in a way that I could unscramble them with the same seed. The scramble part works fine but when I unscramble the scrambled image it leaves some pixels black, I tired using png format since its not being compressed but still no good.

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import random
from datetime import datetime
```

class Scrambler:

```
@staticmethod    
def scramble(key,fileName):
     image = Image.open(fileName)
     pixels = image.load()
     new_image = Image.new(image.mode,image.size)
     new_image_pix = new_image.load()
     seed = 0
     for c in key:
         seed+=ord(c)
     random.seed(seed)
     for i in range(0,(image.size)[0]):
        for j in range(0,(image.size)[1]):
            new_image_pix[i,j] = pixels[random.randint(0,image.size[0]-1),
                                        random.randint(0,image.size[1]-1)]


     new_image.show()
     new_image.save('scrambeld.png')


@staticmethod
def unscramble(key,fileName):
    image = Image.open(fileName)
    pixels = image.load()
    new_image = Image.new(image.mode,image.size)
    new_image_pix = new_image.load()
    seed = 0
    for c in key:
      seed+=ord(c)
    random.seed(seed)
    for i in range(0,(image.size)[0]):
        for j in range(0,(image.size)[1]):
            new_image_pix[random.randint(0,image.size[0]-1),
                          random.randint(0,image.size[1]-1)] = pixels[i,j]

    new_image.show()
    new_image.save('unscarmbeld.png')
```

[original image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv3AN.jpg)

[scrambeld image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBefv.png)

[image after Un Scrambeling:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bAmQ.png)

Much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't insure that every pixel in the original images gets placed (assigned from) in the scrambled image, which means that those pixels won't get filled in in the unscrambled image.